# Static IP / IP Range for Site hosted on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, static-ip-address

Our site is hosted on Google App Engine which means we do not have a server farm with dedicated IP addresses that can be contacted “directly”. It is an elastic farm that spins up with load.

But our client is looking for static ips to route it through firewall and provide suitable access for this site:
"Proxy does not support any voice and video, hence I have to know all the Ip used for this portals so that I can route this via Firewall."

Is there anyway to list all the IP used for a site hosted on Google App engine?

regards,
Kanchan

Comment: Could you please post sample code used so it can be evaluated against what you need?

Comment: Dear Lizz, problem is not related to code, but about access the site inside a corporate network.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can achieve is this:

> App Engine's current range of outgoing IP addresses are encoded in the
>   sender policy framework (SPF) record of
>   _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com. You may need to recursively perform DNS SPF lookups to resolve the entire list of IP ranges. Start
>   by resolving _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/general#static-ip

You could of course do it the other way round and only allow access to your application *from* a specific IP range.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to keep track of GAE ip addresses is not a very good idea. They will most likely change over time without any announcements or heads ups.

You will be better of with a proxy. This project https://github.com/TellusTalk/Node_Proxy is one way to accomplish this.